# RHEL6: repo won't enable

Tags: package-management, redhat-enterprise-linux

Mount DVD

```
[root@rhel66 ~]#  mount /dev/sr0 /media
```

Install the repo metadata

```
[root@rhel66 ~]# cp /media/media.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/rhel6.repo
```

List the repos

```
[root@rhel66 ~]# yum repolist all
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
repo id          repo name                                              status
InstallMedia     Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.6                           disabled
rhel-source      Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6Server - x86_64 - Source     disabled
rhel-source-beta Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6Server Beta - x86_64 - Sourc disabled
repolist: 0
```

Try to enable the repo

```
[root@rhel66 ~]# yum-config-manager --enable InstallMedia
Loaded plugins: product-id
============================== repo: InstallMedia ==============================
[InstallMedia]
bandwidth = 0
base_persistdir = /var/lib/yum/repos/x86_64/6Server
baseurl =
cache = 0
cachedir = /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6Server/InstallMedia
cost = 500
enabled = True
enablegroups = True
exclude =
failovermethod = priority
gpgcadir = /var/lib/yum/repos/x86_64/6Server/InstallMedia/gpgcadir
gpgcakey =
gpgcheck = False
gpgdir = /var/lib/yum/repos/x86_64/6Server/InstallMedia/gpgdir
gpgkey =
hdrdir = /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6Server/InstallMedia/headers
http_caching = all
includepkgs =
keepalive = True
mdpolicy = group:primary
mediaid = 1411733344.627228
metadata_expire = -1
metalink =
mirrorlist =
mirrorlist_expire = 86400
name = Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.6
old_base_cache_dir =
password =
persistdir = /var/lib/yum/repos/x86_64/6Server/InstallMedia
pkgdir = /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6Server/InstallMedia/packages
proxy = False
proxy_dict =
proxy_password =
proxy_username =
repo_gpgcheck = False
retries = 10
skip_if_unavailable = False
ssl_check_cert_permissions = True
sslcacert =
sslclientcert =
sslclientkey =
sslverify = True
throttle = 0
timeout = 30.0
username =
```

List again, still disabled

```
[root@rhel66 ~]# yum repolist all
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
repo id          repo name                                              status
InstallMedia     Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.6                           disabled
rhel-source      Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6Server - x86_64 - Source     disabled
rhel-source-beta Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6Server Beta - x86_64 - Sourc disabled
repolist: 0
```

[From the docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Managing_Yum_Repositories.html) this looks like it simply has to work. But the repository stored on the DVD remains disabled.

Comment: yum install <package> --enablerepo=InstallMedia

Comment: How should I know what the package is called when I can't even list the repo (since I cannot enable it)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [have to modify the file copied into `/etc/yum.repos.d/`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-yum.html#s1-yum-upgrade-system) and add the `baseurl` attribute with the path where the DVD is mounted as value.

```
baseurl=file:///path_to_DVD/
```